# How to connect to default drupal database using php

Tags: database

I have drupal setup on my local machine (Aquia dev desktop). I created a table in my database called "pin_code". I want to write a php script that would involve connecting to the database. I have used the values from my settings.php file. Unfortunately i get the error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Please what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: It may be easiest to just bootstrap Drupal with your external script, and use Drupal's API functionality/db connection to talk to the database. See, for example: http://www.avenuewebmedia.com/drupalbootstrap-connect-drupal-external-php-script

Comment: You can run the script separately using Drush's php-script ...

Comment: @geerlingguy, thanks. However this is the message i get after copying and pasting the code from the link you mentioned. `code`
Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2) in C:\Users\SEYI\Desktop\obs\test.php on line 6

Notice: Use of undefined constant DRUPAL_ROOT - assumed 'DRUPAL_ROOT' in C:\Users\SEYI\Desktop\obs\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 2270
Warning: require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT/includes/errors.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `code`

Comment: `code` C:\Users\SEYI\Desktop\obs\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 2270

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'DRUPAL_ROOT/includes/errors.inc' (include_path='.;C:\Program Files\acquia-drupal\common\pear') in C:\Users\SEYI\Desktop\obs\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 2270 `code` Do i need to edit the code?

Comment: @AgA, thanks, but I have little knowledge of Drush.